# I can't find my question back

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Might look strange, but I can not find my question of yesterday back.

I have posted a question (I think tagged with MySQL and Enum). I got an answer as well.
I tried the suggestion and it worked, so I wanted to say thank you and close the subject.

But how do I find my question back? I can't find a way to find my own questions.

Any suggestion?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229670/restrictions-on-type-enum-not-enough)?

Answer (score 3):

You can see list of all your questions in a certain site from within your profile on that site.

To reach your profile just click your own display name wherever it's shown on the screen, for example it's always visible on the top of every page.

In [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1486108/user1486108) summary you have *Questions* section showing your recent questions, that's the fastest way.

You can also go to the [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1486108/user1486108?tab=questions) of your profile to see all questions you ever asked.

More than that - in your profile on any site you have link to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1606018/user1486108) which has [activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/1606018/user1486108?tab=activity) showing your activity all across the Stack Exchange network.

Note however that if a post you made (question or answer) is deleted, it will no longer be visible in the profile.

Comment: Oké, thanks. I will try this.